# Data-tier in n-tier architecture

Tags: database, n-tier-architecture, data-tier-applications

I have a question about data integrity.

One important role of "data tier" is ensuring data integrity .Is this achievable without the help of "business layer"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity) says: data integrity refers to maintaining and assuring the accuracy and consistency of data over its entire life-cycle,and is a critical aspect to the design, implementation and usage of any system which stores, processes or retrieves data.

From an N-tier architecture point of view, or software architecture in general, each layer has it's own clearly defined scope and purpose and should be decoupled from the other layers providing abstraction and a easy way swiping out functionality.

So to answer your question - YES - data integrity is achievable without the help of the business layer, or any other layer.